# Pseudocode for simple range search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, range, pseudocode

I am working through some practise problem sets for an upcoming CS exam. I was hoping I could get some help figuring out pseudocode for this algorithm:

> Given an array of `n` integers that have been sorted in increasing order, I need to give a pseudocode description of an algorithm to perform a range search on A having complexity `O(r + logn)`, where `r` is the number of outputted points. In other words, given a closed interval `[lo, hi]`, output all the array elements `A[i]` where `lo <= A[i] <= hi`.

---

I understand that the '`r`' portion of the complexity will simply be outputting the elements which are within the interval (having placed them in a separate array in the algorithm).

I am not quite sure how to do this. It is suppose to be just one algorithm. Is recursion necessary? Since the algorithm has to be `log(n)`, dividing the array constantly seems like an idea. I am just confused on how to implement it.

Comment: +1 For a nicely formatted/detailed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dividing the array constantly" is correct.  If you do this by dividing in half every time, this is called a "binary search", which is indeed O(log(n)).

You will have to do the search twice, once for `hi` and once for `lo` but that does not change the order of complexity, since we are multiplying by a constant number of iterations.

Comment: You do *not* have to do the binary search twice. You normally want to find the lower boundary with a binary search, then just iterate linearly outputting items until you reach an item greater than your upper boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the help both of you! I was able to figure it out, and Jerry made a good point about only needing one interval.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: My mistake.  You are correct.  I was assuming that we just needed the indices.  Of course, outputting the elements is in linear time (based on the number of elements that fall in that range), whereas finding the lower bound is logarithmic.

Comment: @JerryCoffin:  In a practical sense, you would want to avoid "outputting" the elements, and just keep a reference to the range in the array.

Comment: @JohnGietzen: In this case, outputting the items is a specific requirement. Otherwise I'd generally agree though.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, think about how you might adapt the [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the first element greater than or equal to `lo` and the last element less than or equal to `hi`.  How long would each search take?  And how would you modify binary search in this fashion?

Comment: Thanks for the help! As Jerry pointed out above, I only needed the lower boundary.